# How set different Node.js environment per app

Tags: node.js, environment

### Scenario

- Node.js runs on a server with Ubuntu Server OS
- On this server runs **4 different Node app**
- **Nginx** is installed and used **as a proxy**, so first app is listening on 8081 port the second on 8082 and so on, but users can access to up with standard port (80/443)
- app runs under **forever**

### Question

it's possible **set** a **different environment per** every **app**?

for example i'd like to have an environment MYSQL_USER set in different way.
every app have a config.js that contain a string as follow:

```
exports.mysql_user = process.env.MYSQL_USER || 'devuser';
```

I see that is possible add some module to manage an external env file.
I'd like manage that **without a module** if is possible.

**There is a way to do that?**

I see that is possible load ENV in this way:

```
ENV_1="first value" ENV_2="second value" node app.js
```

or (in my case)

```
ENV_1="first value" ENV_2="second value" forever start app.js
```

### Conclusion

- **It is possible to automate this?**
- **This approach has contraindications?**
- **It is preferable to use another solution?**

Comment: When user access from standard port which app is receiving the request? you can load the variables from many places as long as you configured this in your application, you can load from database, `.json` files or even command line arguments, or export the variables as you do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass environment variables to NodeJS, yes, you can access the environment with `process.env` [(link)](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env). There is also `process.argv` [(link)](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv), which works similarly. These could be used in a batch or startup script (though careful of overlapping environments, as normal).

Using it in code is pretty straight-forward:

```
var port = 3000;
switch( process.env.ENV_1 )
{
  case "devuser":
    port = 3001;
    break;
  case "admin":
    port = 3002;
    break;
}
console.log("Starting app as '"+ process.env.ENV_1 +"' on port " + port );
process.exit(0);
```

Can be run like this, straight from the command line:

```
> ENV_1=devuser node test.js; ENV_1=admin node test.js
Starting app as 'devuser' on port 3001
Starting app as 'admin' on port 3002
```

And the argument version. Be aware the indexes use for that - same code as above, but `switch`ing on `process.argv[2]` instead.

Runs like this:

```
> node test.js devuser; node test.js admin
Starting app as 'devuser' on port 3001
Starting app as 'admin' on port 3002
```

Comment: why `var console=require('console');` ?

Comment: Edited, that was not needed.

Comment: well, thanks for your answer but... if could avoid switch code inside the app i think is better.
if i have (for example) ten different environment variables per app, it's not very easy pass every var as
ENV_1="devuser" ENV_2="xxx" [...] forever start test.js
there is no way to write env on file and start node process with forever, reading the vars file?
ex. for a file .environment something like
**cat .environment ! forever start app.js**
it works?
and it's a good practice?
heroku or app fog allows change env by panel how they load the environment vars set at node stop/start process?

Comment: This was simply an example of using `process.env` and `process.argv`in your app, which is how I read the question - you could implement them any way you choose inside you app (`switch`es or not). I personally am using a `config.js` file as my environment that is `require()`'d on app start, setting my running environment for development, test, production, etc.

Comment: Also, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173834/using-a-testing-database-with-restify/22178048#22178048) for how I use config files for different environments.